# How to delete blank cells and regroup not empty cells on Google Sheets column

Tags: google-spreadsheets

You have a column, some cells have data, some are empty. How can you regroup the not empty data? example, you have this:

this

is

an

example

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

and you want this:
this
is
an
example

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

like alphabetical order, but in this case order like it is, but without empties

thanks!

[pd capture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3VvH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in case this is useful to someone, my solution was using regex.
^\n will match every new line \n that is at the beginning of the line ^